# populate a select box from a another select box and using database connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have two select boxes: one is country and the other one is cities.
When the user selects a country, the appropriate cities for that country should be populated in the "cities" from the database.

I am new to jquery and javascript and i am not sure how to implement this. It will be appreciated if someone gives me a sample code for performing this functionality. I have no idea and i am pretty much stuck as i am new to the scripting languages.

I am using this in one of my forms  in django framework which is implemented in python.

Thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div { color:red; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select name="country" id="country">
    <option value = "india">india</option>
    <option value = "USA">USA</option>
    <option value = "UK">UK</option>
    <option value = "China">China</option>
    <option value = "Sweden">Sweden</option>
    <option value = "Germany">Germany</option>
  </select>

  <select name="cities" id="cities">
  <option value = ""></option>
  </select>  
  <div></div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have tried to do some basic functions and i was able to get the value of the selected element select box, "country", but i am not sure of what to do next.                      $('#country').change(function() 
 {
  var value = $(this).attr('value');
  alert(value);
 });

Comment: Will you have many cities for each country? Reason I am asking is that it might be worth caching the list of cities on the server and return it to the view and popluate the select box using Javascript instead of hitting the DB all the time.

Comment: @Mikael : actually i need to use the DB because, there is an another complex scenario that i will implementing using the above logic. In that case scenario, there will also be two list boxes, date and time, where when you select a date, the time of purchase should displayed in the time select box dynamically and then using the above two values i will perform additional operations and i should not refresh the page or submit the form.

Comment: OK so in the change function you can make an AJAX call to a view which returns the cities for the given country.

Comment: A  useful options for this can be django smart_select app, that populate one drop down on the base of other.  and is easy to use, please see https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In your template

```
 $('#country').change(function() { 
    var value = $(this).attr('value'); 
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/getcities/",
        type: "GET",
        data: {country : value},
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data) {
         //Popluate combo here by unpacking the json
        }
    });


});
```

In your view:

```
def getcities(request)
    if request.method == "GET":
        country = request.GET["country"]
        cities = Cities.objects.filter(country=country)
        results = [{'city': str(city.name), 'id':city.id} for city in cities]
        json = simplejson.dumps(results)
        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

You will have to map the url /getcities/ to your view in urls.py.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to implement this logic in my code and thanks to you i understood the logic. I have a little trouble of calling the views through the url. in other words, i have defined it in the urls.py and also implemented the view, but the view is not getting called. I do not understand the reason for it not getting called

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Also try changing to GET instead of POST. I have updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: Use Firebug to see what path the code is calling. It could be something wrong with it.

Comment: actually when i changed the method to get, the view is getting called. But for some reason, the request.GET is not able to receive the request from the ajax call

Comment: i got the value through GET by using a getlist() function and it works

Comment: the json = simplejson.dumps(results), when i actually this code, i was not able to print the values from the json object. How am i supposed to do it. I did a normal print statement, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: are you trying to print it in python or in javascript?

Comment: i am trying to print it in views.py and also it will be helpful if u can tell me of how to print those in javascript

Comment: Can you paste the view code in here? If it doesn't print there must be something wrong with the way you are creating it. For using json in javascript, look here: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: actually, i have posted my entire case scenario in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860183/dynamic-jquery-view-in-django , for a ver much better understanding, which is almost similar to the above case and the exact case which i told that i would be implementing

Comment: it works ! it was not working because of the fact that that it was a datetime object, once i converted it into string, the values paased on to the jquery function