# dynamic JQuery view in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, json

my jquery looks like this:

```
$('#id_start_date_list').change(
        function get_time()
        {
            var value = $(this).attr('value');
            alert(value);
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "/getTime/",
                type: "GET",
                data: {start_date : value},         
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {               
                //Popluate combo here by unpacking the json
        }
        });

        });
```

my view.py looks like this:

```
def getTime(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        date_val =  request.GET.get('start_date')                        
        format = '%Y-%m-%d' 
        sd = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_val, format)
        sql_qw = MeasurementTest.objects.filter(start_date = sd)        
        results = [{'start_time': str(date.start_time), 'id_start_time':date.start_time} for date in sql_qw]
        print results                   
        *****json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
        response_var=  json_serializer.serialize(results, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2, use_natural_keys=True)*****

    return HttpResponse(response_var, mimetype="application/json")
```

my html page looks like this:

```
html>
<head>
    <title>date Comparison</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>   
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="/example/" method="post" align= "center">{% csrf_token %}
         <table align = "center">
         <tr>
            <th><label for="start_date_list">Date 1:</label></th>
            <th>        {{ form.start_date_list }}          </th>               
        </tr>                  
        <tr>

        <th><label for="start_time_list">time:</label></th>
        <th><select name="start_time_list" id="start_time_list"></th>
            <option></option>           
        </select>
        <th></th>

        <div id = "log"></div>
        </tr>

        <tr align = "center"><th><input type="submit" value="Submit"></th></tr> 
         </table>         
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see i am getting the value from the select box and i am performing operations on the database and retreiving values and storing it in the json object.

There are two parts that i am totally blind.
First is the json object, where i am not sure whether the results are getting stored in the response_var object.
The second is that, i am not sure how to get values from a json object onto the new list of "start_time_list"

In detail: have i have done anything wrong in the json object initialisation. I have tried to print the respose_var, but it seems not to be printed on the console. Am i using the right syntax? and can someone tell me how to view the values stored in the json object in the view.py

In the similar way, how do i perform operations on the jquery side, to extract values from a json object and how to assign the values of a json object onto a list box by means of sample code and possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the results to json, use [simplejson](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.1.1/docs/index.html):

```
from django.utils import simplejson
def getTime(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    date_val =  request.GET.get('start_date')                        
    format = '%Y-%m-%d' 
    sd = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_val, format)
    sql_qw = MeasurementTest.objects.filter(start_date = sd)        
    results = [{'start_time': str(date.start_time), 'id_start_time':date.start_time} for date in sql_qw]
    print results
    response_var = simplejson.dumps(results)

return HttpResponse(response_var, mimetype="application/json")
```

To access the json object in your javascript, take a look at your ajax request. The success callback is being passed a parameter, `data` in this case. That is the variable containing the server response. So, to access the first element of the resultant array (for instance), you could:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "/getTime/",
  type: "GET",
  data: {start_date : value},         
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {               
    //Popluate combo here by unpacking the json
    data[0];  // This is the first element of the array sent by the server
  }
});
```

Lastly, to modify the html, jQuery provides plenty of methods, such as [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/). It's worth taking a look at the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/). So if you want to build a collection of options for a select tag, you should iterate over the result set using the javascript `for` loop, jQuery `each` method or similar, construct the options (this can be accomplished either concatenating strings or creating DOM elements, which I think is the best solution, as it performs better) and insert them in the html with one of the methods previously mentioned.